# How do I convert a VM of vmware to a VM of virtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-player

Environments: VMware player 7.0 + VirtualBox 4.3.20
Problem: I want convert a VM(win7-32) in vmware to virtualbox, How do it?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/thaniwa/entry/en_how_to_use_vmware

Answer (score 0):

You can load a VMDK directly into virtualbox. Create a new VM, use tell it to existing an existing, and tell virtualbox to the VMDK from the vmplayer VM.

I'd suggest using a copy of the VMDK in case you have trouble booting due to dissimilar hardware, but it probably shouldn't be an issue.

You may also need to re-activate, depending on your licence.

Comment: To Journeyman: I do as your instruction ,but the VM can't be started in VirtualBox, what's the issue？
To cdg: what's the "guest additions"? how do I uninstall it from the VMplayer?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you have to uninstall any "guest additions" in the VMPlayer (or Virtual PC) virtual disk before you try to use it with Virtual Box, or Virtual Box will have various problems. The same thing applies to using one of the programs out there to convert from one format to another. This makes sharing the same Virtual Machine between different "virtualizers" far too much trouble, as you have to uninstall the other virtualizer's "guest additions" and install the second "virtualizer's "guest additions" every time you switch.